# jquery queue problem

Tags: jquery

```
$(".menu-container").animate({top:"25px"}); 
$(".menu-container").animate({top:"-900px"}); 
$(".windows-container").animate({top:"-730px"});
```

hello sir.. i got a problem on queue in jquery.. what i want to do is

```
$(".menu-container").animate({top:"25px"}); ----execute first then after this,

$(".menu-container").animate({top:"-900px"});          --this one and
$(".windows-container").animate({top:"-730px"});       --this one should execute at the same time..
```

i tried this but its not functioning..

```
$(".menu-container").queue(function(){
    $(".menu-container").animate({top:"25px"});
    $(".windows-container").animate({top:"-730px"});
    $(".menu-container").animate({top:"-900px"});
 });
```

---

Comment: i think the last 2 lines are not executing.. i have not seen the .menu-container and did not animate to top:0px;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to start each animation when the previous one finishes, like this:

```
$(".menu-container").animate({top:"25px"}, function() {
    $(".menu-container").animate({top:"-900px"}, function() {
        $(".windows-container").animate({top:"-730px"});
    }); 
});
```

Comment: i tried this.. 

$(".menu-container").animate({top:"25px"}, function() {
                    $(".menu-container").animate({top:"-900px"});
                    $(".windows-container").animate({top:"-730px"});
               });

and it works.. thanks guys.. thank you very much.. :)

Answer (score 1):

animate has a callback function you can use to perform actions after an animation is complete

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```